# How do you create the Parent Product for Amazon Variations?

Tags: amazon, m2e

I've got a **Magento** site that I'm trying to integrate with Amazon using **M2E Pro**, but I'm really struggling to configure the variations.

Amazon is currently listing the simple products as independent items rather than as children within a Parent SKU.

If I try to list the configurable product, M2E Pro throws an error, demanding that a variation be selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.